# how to make the app "keep" data in the screen on react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am new to react native and I am building a shopping list app and use firebase as data storage. Currently I have 4 screens: Register, Login, Menu and shopping list where users can add a shopping list and the information will be sent to firebase. The problem is whenever the user finish creating the list and go back to menu or logout the system, the information disappears from the screen, how can prevent that?

```
    import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity,TextInput, Alert} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import Carrot from '../assets/carrot.png'
import Grocery from '../assets/grocery.png'
import Tomatoes from '../assets/tomatoes.png'
import GroceryBag from '../assets/grocery_bag.jpg'
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';


const ShoppingListScreen = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const addList = () => {
        if(input)
        {
        console.log(input)
        setList([...list, 
        {key:Math.random().toString(), 
        data:input
        }]);
        setInput('');
        };
    }

    const removeList = (inputKey) => {
       setList(list => list.filter(input => input.key != inputKey));
    };   

    const handleSignOut = () => {
        auth
         .signOut()
         .then(() => {
             navigation.replace("Login")
             console.log('User signed out!')
         })
         .catch(error => alert(error.message))
    };
        const sendDataToDB = () =>{
        if(input)
        {
        firebase.database().ref('Shopping Lists/').push({
            list
        }).
        then((data) => {
            console.log('data', data)
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('error', error)
        })
    };
            }
        
    const checkInput= () =>{
        if( !input || input == " ")
        {
            alert("Empty Input")
        }
    };
    
  return(
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        behavior={Platform.OS === "android" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={styles.container}
        behavior="padding"
        backgroundColor="white">
        
        
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Image style={styles.carrot}
        source={Carrot} 
        resizeMode="contain">     
        </Image>
        
        <Image style={styles.grocery}
        source={Grocery} 
        resizeMode="contain">     
        </Image>

        <Image style={styles.tomatoes}
        source={Tomatoes} 
        resizeMode="contain">     
        </Image>

        <Image style={styles.grocery_bag}
        source={GroceryBag} 
        resizeMode="contain">     
        </Image>
    </View>
    
    <ScrollView>
        {list.map((input) =>
        <TouchableOpacity 
        key = {input.key}>
        <View style = {styles.listViewer}
        >  
        <Text style = {styles.viewerText}>{input.data}</Text>
        
        
        <TouchableOpacity>
      
        <View
        style = {{
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderRadius: 50, 
            padding: 5,
            width: 30,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
        <Text style = {styles.viewerText}>
        <AntDesign
        name='delete'
        color={'#802b00'}
        onPress={() => removeList(input.key)}>
        </AntDesign>
        </Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>)}
        </ScrollView> 
   
    <View style={styles.footer}></View>
    
    <View style={styles.signOutItem}>
           <MaterialIcons 
           name='logout'
           size={50}
           color={'#fff'}
           onPress={handleSignOut}
           /> 
           <Text style={styles.LogOutLabels}>Logout</Text>
       </View>
       
       <View style={styles.homeItem}>
           <AntDesign 
           name='home'
           size={50}
           color={'#fff'}
           onPress={() => {navigation.navigate("Home")}}
           /> 
           <Text style={styles.homeLabels}>Home</Text>
       </View>
        
       <View style={styles.plusItem}>
           <MaterialIcons 
           name='add-circle'
           size={50}
           color={'#802b00'}
           onPress={() => {checkInput();addList(); sendDataToDB()}}
         
           /> 
       </View>
       <TextInput style={{flex: 1}}
       style={styles.listInput}
       placeholder='Enter List Name'
       value={input}
       onChangeText={text => setInput(text)}
       autoCapitalize='none'>
       </TextInput>
       
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default ShoppingListScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    viewerText:{
        fontSize:15,
        color:'#fff',
        

    },
    listViewer:{
    justifyContent:"space-between",
    backgroundColor:'#802b00',
    width: 350,
    padding: 10,
    margin: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    flexDirection:"row",
    
    },
    carrot:{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 100,
        height: 200,
        opacity: 0.2,
        right: 100,
        bottom: 70,
    },
    grocery:{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 100,
        height: 200,
        opacity: 0.2,
        left: 105,
        bottom: -355,
    },
    tomatoes:{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 100,
        height: 200,
        opacity: 0.2,
        right: 90,
        bottom: -350,
        
    },
    grocery_bag:{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 100,
        height: 200,
        opacity: 0.2,
        left: 90,
        bottom: 80,
       
    },
    footer:{
        backgroundColor:'#802b00',
        width: '100%',
        color :'white',
        height:100,
        position:'absolute',
        bottom:0,
    },
    signOutItem:{
        bottom:-132,
        left: 45,
    },
    LogOutLabels:{
        color:'#ffff',
        right:5,
    },
     homeItem:{
        bottom: -65,
        right: 30,
        color: 'black',
    },
    homeLabels:{
        color:'#ffff',
        right: -5,
    },
    plusItem:{
        bottom: 100,
        left: 150,
    },
    listInput:{
        bottom: 147,
        right: 50,
        paddingHorizontal:15,
        paddingVertical:10,
        borderRadius:10,
        marginTop:5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'#C0C0C0',
        color:'#000000',
        width: '60%',
       
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible solutions:

1. Refetch data from firebase when users navigate back to the screen - Not
   best UX ever. React navigation provides `useFocusEffect` hook for that.
2. Save last user-added data in Async Storage and retrieve when the user
   revisit screen.
3. Use Redux with `redux-persist` and persist portion of that app
   frequently needed data.